# How to have a Open VZ VPS running a PPTP VPN, run without having PUTTY open?

Tags: vpn, vps

I just set up a VPN on my VPS server. It works great, except that once I close PUTTY, the VPN is shut down. I tried to use screen, but I don't know how to get that working with the VPN. What can I do to get this running without having PUTTY open?

pptpd (pid  1402) is running...

Comment: Why use a PPTP VPN at all? Why not just use an SSH tunnel with port forwarding? VPNs should be used for connecting to subnets, not hosts.

Comment: PPTP is required for what I'm using it for.

Comment: Which is what exactly? Context helps a lot in these situations. Also, which OS are you running and what version?

Comment: It is for an app on iOS. The only option is PPTP. I followed this tutorial to set it up. http://www.zedt.eu/tech/linux/setting-pptp-vpn-server-centos-openvz-vps/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up PPTP to be run as a daemon/service. Based on your linked guide, it looks like you're running a RedHat-based distribution (most likely CentOS), so you will need to issue the `service pptpd restart` command over SSH to start the service, which will then run in the background.

If you can't connect to it and you can confirm that the service is running while connected over SSH, try `ps -ef | grep ppp` to check for running processes, and `netstat -anp | grep ppp` to check for processes that are listening to network ports.

If your service is running and listening, your issue could be either your local iptables firewall, or an upstream firewall or configuration from your VPS provider - several OpenVZ VPS providers that I know of do this.

You also haven't mentioned how you're connecting to the VPN, but needless to say that you'll need to use the VPS' public IP address, not the local IP you've configured (this is the IP range that clients get assigned when they connect).

Comment: Yes I am connecting though the IP address. The first command you gave me displays this "root      1405  1364  0 20:01 pts/1    00:00:00 grep ppp", and the second one does not display anything.

Comment: That would suggest that your PPTP service either isn't running or isn't starting, so your problem seems to be coniguration-based. Can you edit your original question with the content of `/etc/pptpd.conf`, and also the output of `service pptpd status`? Also, check the contents of `/var/log/messages` for any output relating to the `pptp` service - this could give you a clue as to why the service isn't starting properly.

Comment: The VPN works just fine when PUTTY is open, in fact I'm using it right now. The output of that was "pptpd (pid  1402) is running...". I don't really understand what any of this means, does it say the VPN is running?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I slipped into Debian. Adjust the `grep` commands to read `pptp` rather than `ppp`. Also check the log-file I mentioned to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: "root      1402     1  0 20:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/pptpd
root      1423  1364  0 20:13 pts/1    00:00:00 grep pptp" and "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1402/pptpd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2037555868 1402/pptpd"